# An if statement that always returns true even when it should return false

Tags: php, file, size, constraints, uploading

I've seen many references in many forums to this statement in regards to uploading files

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
```

Yet when I use this, it seems that no matter what the size of the file being uploaded, this always returns true.
I have placed echo statements like these to try to determine what is going on

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000) {
   echo "The file size (".$_FILES["file"]["size"].") is smaller than 20000" ;}
  else {
     echo "The file size (".$_FILES["file"]["size"].") is larger than 20000" ;}
```

and what I will get echoed is something like *"The file size (2000000) is smaller than 20000"* and never will I see *"The file size (2000000) is larger than 20000"* regardless of the size of the uploaded file

Any help would be much appreciated....

Thanks to all who responded, my problem turned out to me a simple typo. Sorry to waste your time with such a rookie mistake

Comment: Please add form html code and make sure `type="file"` name is file like `name="file"`

Comment: @manoj.admlab Why would that make a difference? Wouldn't that affect both the `if` and `echo` the same?

Comment: Check carefully for typos. Is that a cut-and-paste of the actual code, or did you retype it in SO? Please post the real code. Also, it might help if you posted `var_dump($_FILES)`.

Comment: @Barmar If name is different then the issue may be because the value `$_FILES["file"]["size"]` is not getting set

Comment: I just tried this in PHPfiddle - I can't reproduce your result. It seems to work fine.

Comment: @manoj.admlab But then it wouldn't show up in the `echo`.

Comment: @Barmar You are correct in that case it wouldn't show up in the `echo`

Comment: Have you tried doing a var_dump($_FILES["file"]) to see what's actually inside the array?

Answer (score 0):

- check value of $_FILES["file"]["size"] first by echoing echo
  $_FILES["file"]["size"];
- check values of $_FILES by print_r($_FILES);
  Depending on the values u can check for conditions